# How to Pivot a Table with columns like Tunnel1, Tunnel2,

Tags: sql-server

I have an odd table in SQL Server that looks like it was created specifically to allow people to enter setpoints easier, but it isn't great with querying.  I have the following table:

[image: Product Table]

I have a more properly indexed Tunnels Table:

[image: Tunnels Table]

I would like to be able to join so that Product 1 would show 4 rows with the following columns:

[TunnelName] [ProductName] [LbsHr] [LbsStroke]

Is this possible to pivot/join in this manner based upon the crappy table structure (which is legacy and some VBA programs use, so I can't change it)?

Comment: oops, sorry about that.  I didn't think of image vs text.  Is there a way to unpivot multiple columns like I have?  Trying to google that now.  I've already unpivoted Tunnel1-4.

Comment: just unpivot your columns?